# install4j installer is not picking the oracle-jdk path it take by default open-jdk in ubuntu

Tags: install4j

I have installed open-jdk-7 and oracle-jdk-8 in Ubuntu 13.10 and i have set JAVA_HOME.
when i tried with java -version give me oracle jdk path but when i m trying to install software in Ubuntu which is generated by the install4j.
so that it is taking the open-jdk path. but open-jdk is not setting in the path variable.code is below for picking the dynamic jdk.

```
{
JVMSelector.JVMLocation[] locations = JVMSelector.getJVMLocations("${compiler:sys.javaMinVersion}", "${compiler:sys.javaMaxVersion}", true, null);
String  jdkHome = locations[ locations.length-1].getJavaHome().getAbsolutePath();
}
```

i need to set the oracle jdk in install4j. what i am messing here ..?

Comment: In what directories are both JREs installed?

Comment: both jdk installed in /usr/lib/jvm/ directories.

Comment: Maybe the JRE is another array element returned by JVMSelector.getJVMLocations and not in the last one?